# Qt dragEnterEvent not being called

Tags: c++, qt

Here i got a problem that my application could not receive drag drop event when i launch my App with `QProcess::startDetached` method. But when i launch my app with double click, it works well and there is a red forbidden icon

nomally it has red icon

[image]

but when my app launch by `QProcess::startDetached`, the icon turns black, and my application could not accept drag event any more(include dragEnterEvent etc.)

now it becomes black icon

[image]

my OS is Windows10  64bits, hope someone can help me~ THX

Comment: Could you please show us relevant parts of your source code.

Comment: `void KLXiaoUpdater::exitAndStartupApp()
{
 QString appPath = KLFileUtil::getStartupAppFile();
 if (!QProcess::startDetached(appPath))
 {
  QMessageBox::warning(this, "warning", QString("Can not run process ") + appPath);
 }

 close();
}
`      i start up my app using this way, the app which i called has override the dragEnterEvent() function, but when i dragged file to my app drag drop area, this event can not be called

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be present if you run the process from a process with enhanced privileges.

More information here:

[Q: Why Doesn’t Drag-and-Drop work](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2010/01/28/q-why-doesnt-drag-and-drop-work-when-my-application-is-running-elevated-a-mandatory-integrity-control-and-uipi/)

[User Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Interface_Privilege_Isolation)

[ChangeWindowMessageFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-changewindowmessagefilter)